# Privacy: Underscored prototype properties or encapsulated variables?

Tags: javascript, instance-variables

Something has been bugging me, like people realize something I don't. I'm looking at a FOSS example, (simplified below)... whenever I have a class in JavaScript, I prefer Crockford's variable hiding methodology:

```
var MyObject = function(handler) {
  var x = 1, y = 2;
  function myFunction() {
    handler(x + y);
  }
  return {
    "myFunction" : myFunction
  }
}
```

Some developers, though, use underscored private properties.

```
var MyObject = function(handler) {
  this._handler = handler;
}
MyObject.prototype._x = 1;
MyObject.prototype._y = 2;
MyObject.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  this._handler(this._x + this._y);
}
```

I understand the difference, but at the risk of sounding stupid: is there an advantage to one over the other that I'm not seeing?  I mean, I dislike the "private" notation; they're not private.  I realize the prototype chain is shared between objects, but they're private.  Short of altering x and y across all objects at runtime, or saving memory, I'm not sure of the reason.

I'm sure there's a good reason, but if someone cares to enlighten me further, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like Crockford's work, I'd suggest watching his JavaScript series where he describes why he avoids using underscores and prefers camelNotation.

http://www.yuiblog.com/crockford/

To answer your question directly, there is no performance advantage for using underscores, it is simply a programming style preference.

Comment: You're talking about underscores purely from the perspective of naming. The OP is talking about the design pattern of using implicitly private variables (as denoted by underscore) vs. explicit private variables (enforced by closures).

Comment: Thanks.  I just refactored this FOSS object to use "true" private vars/closures, and it works the same.  I'm going to run some performance tests out of curiosity...

...but from a pragmatic perspective, the code is cleaner now, (to me), and the API is much cleaner... not to mention the passivity insurance.

Comment: @Box9, have you watched Crockford's explanation on why underscores are meaningless in JavaScript? If not, I'd suggest a quick watch. :-)

Comment: Let me also be clear: I wasn't asking about _ directly, more about why prototypal inheritance with exposed "private" vars was preferable to encapsulation... but I think most of this thread answered that?

Comment: @Lance, I've heard plenty from both sides of the argument, and seeing that these videos are so popular, I doubt that those arguments were not already influenced by Crockford. Nonetheless, I wouldn't mind watching the bit you're talking of. Do you know the exact video it was in, as there are quite a few :P

Comment: @Box9, I believe he goes over the majority of this discussion in the first two videos. It is quite long though, but well worth your time.

Comment: Are you sure? Those seem to be all about history. Care to summarize his argument about underscores?

Answer (score 0):

Three reasons for using `_` notation:

1. As you mentioned, **performance**. Functions are not recreated with each construction.
2. **Debugging**. It's easy to view all the properties of an object at runtime.
3. **Structure**. It's easy to break parts of the code into different files, or inherit properties in child "classes". Variables made private by closures restricts how you can organise your code. This is *kind of* like the argument to use protected/friend variables versus private variables in OOP languages.

There are other arguments in either direction, but it gets more philosophical - about whether to trust programmers with your code or to enforce "good practice", but I won't go there ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you on point 2, no doubt.  In my case point 1 doesn't come into play, (you'd have to see the source). I kind of see your point on #3... but I'd have to see an example to be sure if it's really a benefit to split up the prototypal inheritance across files; I don't think you'd want to... but there's prolly an example to prove me wrong.

Comment: @Clint, it may have worked for your situation, but any functions **not** within the MyObject function will not have access to `x` and `y`. In other words, the MyObject function is forced to be one huge function if it gets more complex. Agreed about performance though, definitely not a major concern in most applications.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I encapsulate functions in the same constructor and expose an API, (by returning an object of "exposed" functions and variables).

Comment: @Clint, which is perfectly valid (it's called the module pattern by the way) but the downside is that it's not easy to split myobject into a core file and an extras file, for example, nor is it easy to extend it to a mySpecialObject class. I'm not trying to promote either pattern, as ultimately you'll need to use both if your objects become more complex - module pattern for temporary working variables and public properties for stateful data, and an underscore to serve simply as a warning that use of the property is undocumented.

Comment: an excellent point re: extension. In this case, extension is not a desired trait. I'm not one to create many extensible (or even constructible) objects; I tend to write singletons for the most part. Definitely giving me food for thought, thanks!